# regarding uses of credential.json of google calendar API

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

So, I made an application using python and google calendar API, where I have to give a reference of credentials.json (I downloaded it from google calendar API website). Now, If someone else uses my application, they get an message of "Google hasn’t verified this app", which is cool but I want to know, can someone misuse that credentials.json against me or that credentials.json is a reference to user and google that "This author is accessing some environment"?

Actually, I'm new in this field so I don't know much more about details.

Answer (score 0):

You should **NOT** be giving anyone access to your credentials.json file from google developer console. This is part of your application.

It is against Googles [TOS](https://developers.googleblog.com/2014/11/subject-changes-to-google-apis-terms-of.html) to share this file with anyone.   This file is only for your application.

If you share it with someone they can then create an application and to all apparent purposes they appear to be you.  IF they start to spam google or if they leak user data, it will be your application that will be seen as at fault.

Your application also needs to be verified as your only going to have about 100 users before its going to get locked down until you do verify it.